# Updating $scope vars in function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.myVar = cheese;

function please(){
  $scope.myVar = "New Value";
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', please);
```

I am confused by this, I have var "cheese" which is in the html, I expect that when I clicked a google marker this would change the html to "New Value" as ng-click does.

What happens is if I put an alert in the function it will alert "New Value" but this doesnt change the var outside of the function.

Tried different ways

myVar = "New Value"
var myVar = "New Value"

I suspect it has something to do with global and local variables but just learning angular so I have been confused a bit.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `$apply` because the call doesn't come from inside of angular.js

```
function please(){
  $scope.$apply(function() {
    $scope.myVar = "New Value";
  });
}
```

Further reading [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply).

Comment: Hero! You bet me to editing the syntax :p

Thanks also for the further reading!

Comment: Yes, you're welcome. I recently ran into a similar problem myself.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring please() as a $scope function:

```
$scope.myVar = cheese;

$scope.please = function () {
  $scope.myVar = "New Value";
}

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', $scope.please());
```